# React.createRef current type in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to find what to type React.createRef as. Header is a custom component.
**header.current** always says

> (property) React.RefObject.current: unknown Object is of type
> 'unknown'.

I can set it to type `<any>` but that's the easy way out. How do I get Typescript to play nice and stop complaining.

```
Example: React.createRef<any>()
```

Fully code:

```
   const header = React.createRef();
    const { container } = render(
      <Header{...props} headerRef={header} />,
    );
    const el = header.current.getButtonElement("button");
```

I've even tried setting it to a HTMLDivElement which is what it returns.

```
const header = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();
```

but the below still gives me an error:
(property) React.RefObject.current: HTMLDivElement | null
Object is possibly 'null'.

```
const el = header.current.getButtonElement("button");
```

Comment: Passing `HTMLDivElement` is correct, however the issue is, you can't call `header.current` directly afterwards, because the header.current can be null.  It's only once the associated div element has mounted, will `header.current` have a reference to that element.  Where are you using `const el` ?

Comment: I'm calling it in a unit test. If I use <any> then ref works but when I use HTMLDivElement it doesn't

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This makes sense. TypeScript is trying to warn you that calling getButtonElement on something that MIGHT be undefined is "dangerous". You can work around this by refining the type first, like this:

```
const header = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();

// In test
const currentHeader = header.current;
if (!currentHeader) {
    // Handle the case where header isn't set yet
}

currentHeader.getButtonElement("button"); // At this point TypeScript knows currentHeader can't be null so the type check passes
```

Comment: Yes it gets the job done but its dirty, similar to <any> My question is more about best practice in this situation than about getting the job done. In saying that yes this would work and I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you think this is dirty. I'd rather say this is clean because you work with the type system you're using. This is how TypeScript is designed to handle potentially null types. Though I understand that putting this in your test code feels bulky.

Comment: @me-me Here is an article about exactly your "problem" https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/react-refs-with-typescript-a32d56c4d315, they suggest using the ! (non null assertion operator) to make it a bit cleaner, maybe that fits better into your test code?